# Got all my files in onedrive with .lockit extension

Tags: windows

I have found today that all the files in my onedrive folder have an extension .lockit and I can not access them. I could not get back previous versions, onedive reports an error when I try, Is hits a Virus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That extension appears to be associated with Ransomware.

You might be able to decrypt your files using a tool from a company called [Emsisoft](https://www.emsisoft.com/ransomware-decryption-tools/cyborg) after you have removed the malware which originally encrypted the files.